# A set of radio buttons are displayed first, and then the stars later appear

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery with the Star Rating Plugin from the following site http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/# . The page loading A set of radio buttons are displayed first, and then the stars later appear. I would like to just display the stars, instead of having the radio 
buttons flickering for a moment, is it possible?

Comment: consider to post some html-markup

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the radio buttons initially, and only show them after calling `.rating()`. The stars would still appear from nowhere, but better than the radio buttons flashing.